# Choice for multi-platform application development

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, starling-framework

I like actionscript very much and did a project with Apache Flex 4.12. Originally my mobile application was built in mxml and the performance was awful. Then I rewrite the application with single line mxml file and the rest of the project in pure as3, the performance is much better.

Now I have another project, it is an multi-platform informational application with some e-commerce capabilities target on both desktop and mobile platform and need to decide, on performance/flexibility/scalability wise, should I stick with Flex (mxml) / Flex (pure as3) / or Pure AS3 with Starling+FeathersUI+as3-signal?

I was thinking to shift into the Starling approach, however I see improvements from the Flex 4.14 release, anyone can give me a direction that which approach is more promising in long term?

Sorry for my bad English as I am not a native user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into Haxe (www.haxe.org) and OpenFL (www.openfl.org) as an alternative to Starling.

Haxe is a programming language that is very similar to action script 3.
OpenFL - open flash library is a framework for Haxe programming language.

The benefit: of Haxe + OpenFL are:

- Astounding performance
- Fast and easy development
- Non-existing learning curve for AS3 programmer ( you might need to spend 10 min learning about loops and casting though )
- 99% same API as the Flash API

I don't recommend Starling because: it's still AIR and you won't want it, the performance is below average, you'll need to re-write your whole code-base for Starling, you won't be able to port your game outside of Starling without rewriting it again and the fact that you won't be able to compile to many different platforms other than the currently supported ones.

Comment: Is this appropriate or commonly used for enterprise development?  I.e. data-heavy applications with lots of input fields, complex screens, complex validation rules, highly dynamic UI screens and so on.  Games--fine, but what about the "show me lots of data and input forms and interactive charts" kind of use case?  How well does it integrate with a JEE server?  Is this essentially a direct competitor with Apache FlexJS?

Comment: Yes it is. Many large companies use Haxe (TiVo is the largest I know) and many game developers are using OpenFL. Also Haxe is a very mature language, very similar to C# in many ways, but serves a different purpose on a larger scale.

Comment: Do you think Haxe still retain the powerful feature of as3 like first class citizens Function and closure? How is the event system looks like? Can it generate native code and executables and run without other software? what are the native platform support? In AIR with ANE I can achieve almost everything that the native platform can do from push notification to RS232 COM port communications. Performance wise, starling let me show 500 moving objects on the screen still having 20fps on my iPhone 5s. If Haxe can achieve these I would give it a try.

Comment: 1) Haxe is indépendant from AS3, it's just a superset of ECMAScript, just like JavaScript, AS3, C# etc.
2) Event system is same as in AS3 but you can make even more complex systems, like signals etc.
3) It does generate native code without a wrapper. It's actually very cool and powerful, check it out, there are tons of samples.
4) You can also use ANE's with Haxe if you want.
5) I personally made a framework for the Tilesheet class and I can render over 20k objects on iPod Touch. So you should definitely try it.

Comment: Is there an RIA-like framework out there similar to what Adobe/Apache Flex brings in terms of UI functionality and integration with JEE servers (ex. RMI)?  Would it involve servlets and use of 3rd party libs for parsing of json/xml?  Hibernate friendly?  Trying to determine if this is a productive option for use with a Java back end without loss of the capabilities we already have.

Comment: @Perce, yes, there's OpenFL, Haxepunk, HaxeFlixel and even Starling ports. When you explore `haxelib` you'll find that there are many many libraries for Haxe, some as ported from AS3

Comment: OpenFL and HaxeFlixel appear to be very game oriented, is anyone actually using them for data centric business apps? Are they going to have things like data grids, auto completion in pull down menus, or other "work" UI components? (The other lib is blocked where I work probably because it's in-fact game related, to illustrate part of the problem.) Not trying to give a hard time but to use Haxe in a serious business application, I'd need to know that there are others doing the same and that there are SDKs out there that cater to those specific needs. It's a little too risky otherwise.

Comment: @Perce just use Haxe API, it has all the things you've mentioned. There's also a library called haxeui - very powerful UI library and a lot of samples too: http://haxeui.org/